# Update datatable and show new value

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to update datatable and print out updated row but I am getting an old value. Here is my code:

```
   Public Shared zadnjiBrojevi As DataTable
...

    aaaa.ItemsSource = Globals.zadnjiBrojevi
    Dim lastnr As Integer
    Dim result() As DataRow = Globals.zadnjiBrojevi.Select("tip = " & tipoviDokumenataCbox.SelectedItem.tag & "")
    For Each row As DataRow In result
        lastnr = row(1)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("Last number is: " & lastnr)

    Dim myRow() As Data.DataRow
    myRow = Globals.zadnjiBrojevi.Select("tip = '" & tipoviDokumenataCbox.SelectedItem.tag & "'")
    myRow(0)("lastnr") = myRow(0)("lastnr") + 1

    Dim filename As String = Globals.rootPath & "ZadnjiBrojevi.xml"
    Globals.zadnjiBrojevi.WriteXml(filename, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
    Console.WriteLine("Dodan upis!")
```

In console i am always getting "Last number is: 4443". But GridControl "aaaa" shows updated values. And "writexml" writes updated values.

Comment: There's a lack of context here to know what you are doing, but I suspect it is because you set `lastnr` in a loop. It will of course always end up with the value of the last iteration.

Comment: @Crowcoder Well, I am showing value of a row and then updating it. On next run i am showing a value again and updating it again. No matter how many times i run the function, console writes same number but 'writexml' writes different (updated) data.